# How to display all the data from table?

Tags: javascript, html

1.This is my code for my HTML table where I'm unable to display the data from it using my javascript code below.

```
<table id="empTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>SimiScore</th>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Introversion/Extraversion</th>
      <th>Intuitive/Observant</th>
      <th>Thinking/Feeling</th>
      <th>Judging/Perceiving</th>
    </tr>  
    {% for doc in docs %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{doc["type"]}}</td>
      <td>{{doc["Simiscore"]}}</td>
      <td>{{doc["Rank"]}}</td>
      <td>{{doc["Introversion/Extraversion"]}}</td>
      <td>{{doc["Intuitive/Observant"]}}</td>
      <td>{{doc["Thinking/Feeling"]}}</td>
      <td>{{doc["Judging/Perceiving"]}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<p><input type="button" id="bt" value="Show Table Data" onclick="showTableData()" /></p>
<p id="info"></p>
```

2.This is my javascript code to display the data, but I'm unable to display it

```
<script>
    function showTableData() {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "";
        var myTab = document.getElementById('empTable');
        // LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW OF THE TABLE AFTER HEADER.
        for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {
        // GET THE CELLS COLLECTION OF THE CURRENT ROW.
            var objCells = myTab.rows.item(i).cells;
        // LOOP THROUGH EACH CELL OF THE CURENT ROW TO READ CELL VALUES.
            for (var j = 0; j < objCells.length; j++) {
                info.innerHTML = info.innerHTML + ' ' + objCells.item(j).innerHTML;
            }
            info.innerHTML = info.innerHTML + '<br />';     // ADD A BREAK (TAG).
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not very clear what you mean by "display the table". What happens when you run this code and what is different than expected? What are expected results? Any errors thrown in dev tools console? These are the sorts of debugging details you need to provide when you have problems and are looking for assistance

Comment: When I run this code I'll be able to print a table with values but I'm not able to print the data from the table. The expected results are to be able to retrieve data from the table and print them. There are no errors when I click the show table data button there is no output either.

Answer (score 0):

{

```
   $(document).ready(function()
 {
$.ajax({
    url: "getjson.php", 
    type: "POST",    
    dataType:"json",   
    success: function (response) 
    {
      var trHTML = '';
      $.each(response, function (key,value) {
         trHTML += 
            '<tr><td>' + value.id + 
            '</td><td>' + value.konu + 
            '</td><td>' + value.aciklama + 
            '</td><td>' + value.giris_tarih + 
            '</td><td>' + value.degistirilme_tarih + 
            '</td><td>' + value.ad_soyad + 
            '</td><td>' + value.email + 
            '</td></tr>';     
      });

        $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
    }   
});
```

});

```
 }
```

this is an example you can use